# Pet Peeve (notation for limits assumes uniqueness...)

Tags: limits, reference-request

I suppose I should disguise this rant as a question.

**Q:** Are there any calculus books that give the definition of limits in a logically correct manner? (See below for the problem I'm complaining about with the typical presentation.)

Teaching baby complex. The book defines "$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=w$" as usual, and then of course the first result is that limits are unique if they exist:

> > **Thm.** If $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=w_1$ and $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=w_2$ then $w_1=w_2$.

This appears literally trivial:

**"Proof.**" $w_1=\lim_{z\to  a}f(z)=w_2$, qed.

There are a few sharp students in the class, actually interested in math, so I feel I should point out why that's bogus; the theorem as stated *looks* like it has zero content.

The point is we have no business using the notation $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$ until after we've proved uniqueness, because the notation, especially if read "*the* limit..." presupposes uniqueness.

To do it right we should instead  define "$f(z)\to w$ as $z\to a$", prove uniqueness, and *then* introduce the notation $\lim$. Making it clear why uniqueness is actually something that requires proof...

Comment: Is it possible to create a tag for mathematical rant?

Comment: I totally agree with you. An alternative would be using "a limit of $f$ as $z\to a$" instead of "the limit of $f$ as $z\to a$", at least until you prove uniqueness.

Comment: You mean like $i$ is the square root of $-1$ or $2$ is the cube root of $8$ or  $0$ is the first natural number?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Yes, saying "_a_ limit is ... if ..." would solve the problem, but of course if we say that we're still in trouble with the notation. One could define $Lim$ to be the (_the_) set of all limits...

Comment: Even worse: the notation $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ entices beginners to use it even when there is no limit.

Comment: Well, introducing a set of all the limits would be nicely married with a definition based on sequences (transport principle):$$Lim(f,a):=\{\ell\in\mathbb{C}\mid f(z_n)\to\ell\text{ for some sequence }z_n\to a\}.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, that's a problem, and yes that's bad, but I don't know about "even worse": They're already for example used to the idea that the notation $1/z$ does not imply there is such a thing for every $z$.

Comment: Do you also mind when people write $a/b$ when they haven't first proven exactly one $x$ satisfies $a=xb$ (or equivalently, they haven't checked $b\ne0$)?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, come to think of it. Typically "they" prove very early that "inverses are unique", and no, they shouldn't really use the notation $b^{-1}$ until after proving that (because otherwise one can give an equivalent bogus proof). Doesn't come up for me since I don't teach that class...

Comment: You could go the "Definition/Theorem" route where the definition is justified with an existence/uniqueness result when stated

Comment: For what it's worth, Bourbaki, Topologie Générale, chapter I does it the right way.
It's also probably not the best book to give to students who see the definition of a limit for the first time. It also uses filters for limits and devellops them first over non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @RobinCarlier That would be "interesting", using Bourbaki as the text for Calc I. (When I was working on _Complex Made Simple_ the dept head suggested in all seriousness that I might want to teach the _undergrad_ complex class to try out the presentation on  some students...)

Comment: As English is not my mother's tongue, I have some difficulty with some expressions, in particular "teaching baby complex" : could you say in  few words what you mean by that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JeanMarie "baby complex" was an informal term for the undergraduate class in complex variables, typically using a book like Churchill. "baby" because we don't expect the students to prove anything non-trivial or to really have a solid grasp of the theory, as we would in the graduate course. (Analogously, when people refer to "Rudin" as a book they typically mean _Real and Complex Analysis_, while "baby Rudin" is his _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_.)

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I teach limits in advanced calculus, the first step is teaching the definition of *convergence of a sequence*:

> **Definition:** Given a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)$ and a real number $L$, the sequence $(x_n)$ *converges* to $L$ if *[... we all know what goes here ...]*

After a few simple examples, I immediately prove:

> **Theorem:** Given a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)$ and real numbers $L,M$, if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $L$ and the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $M$ then $L=M$.

and then I define

> **Definition:** $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ is equal to the unique number to which $(x_n)$ converges.

where the previous theorem is used to justify uniqueness, and therefore well-definedness.

I see that my textbook does indeed follow this same line of development: Advanced Calculus, by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick.

Comment: Yeap, but how could this be extended to *functional* limits? I mean, what would be a sound definition of convergence?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος: "a function $f$ converges to $L$ as $x\to a$ if... " should suffice.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος "$f(x_n)$ converges to $L$ for every sequence $)x_n)$ converging to $a$."

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to think of presenting these ideas in the "wrong" order as an [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation). They've said something like:

> Write $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=L$ iff $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall z\ne a(|z-a|<\delta\implies|f(z)-L|<\epsilon)$. By the triangle inequality, if such an $L$ exists for given $a,\,f$ it is unique, thereby mandating the notation $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$ for $L$.

whereas you'd recommend:

> Call $L$ a $z\to a$ limit of $f(z)$ iff $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall z\ne a(|z-a|<\delta\implies|f(z)-L|<\epsilon)$. By the triangle inequality, if such an $L$ exists for given $a,\,f$ it is unique, thereby mandating the notation $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$ for this $L$.

Every time you see someone write $f(n)=O(g(n))=O(h(n))$ when they really mean something like $f(n)\in O(g(n))=O(h(n))$, you encounter a similar abuse of notation in which we write $=$ when we mean "this would be an example of that" (never mind for the moment whether "this" is on the left- or right-hand side of the spurious $=$), but it doesn't matter because of an appropriate trivial uniqueness result.

I think part of the reason this can be so annoying is the slow build-up of the ideas. I don't know whether any specific textbook (or online PDF, for that matter) takes the second textbox's approach, but perhaps you'll find something that makes either approach so succinct readers don't have time to be misled. Whether it *should* be that succinct [is a tricky issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246773).

Comment: Well of course an abuse of notation is exactly what it is - the word "notation" came up a few times in the rant. If "they" actually said what's in the first box that wouldn't  bother me nearly as much - in fact they define $\lim$ and then prove uniqueness a page or two later, _after_ examples, etc, that seem to talk about _the_ limit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich OK, but my point is abuses of notation aren't intrinsically problematic; in fact, many popular kinds might never be "corrected" with something else. I can't speak for sources I haven't read, but if they deviate from the first box in the way your comment describes, the issue is they've left it too long to walk back the first equation's damage, not that they started by taking its approach.

Comment: Fine, an abuse of notation is not intrinsically problematic. A presentation that makes it look like there's nothing to prove  regarding uniqueness of limits _is_ problematic.

Comment: @DavidCUllrich Now that I agree with. It's not clear to me how anyone can give that misleading impression without omitting the limit's definition altogether, unless ideas are separated too much.

Comment: Another difference: Saying "if such an L exists it is unique" is not at all objectionable, because there's nothing there that presupposes uniqueness, or appears to. As opposed to "if $\lim=w_1$ and $\lim=w_2$ then $w_1=w_2$."

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff annoys me too.

Unfortunately, I can't give a book recommendation, but I can recommend a way to present the material. First, teach that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x),$$ is, in general, a set. For instance, if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between topological spaces, we can define that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ equals the set of all $y \in Y$ such that for every punctured neighbourhood $B$ of $y$, there is a punctured neighbourhood $A$ of $x$ such that the image of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

(You can replace this with the real analysis definition if it's more appropriate.)

Then you can prove that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$$ has at most one element assuming the codomain is Hausdorff. Or if that's too advanced, do it all using metric spaces. Then you explain that when people say that the limit exists, they mean that it has at least one element. Then you add a further stipulation that we'll tend to identify $x$ with the singleton $\{x\}$ except in situations where this can cause confusion. Thus, one can typically regard $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ as an element of $Y$, unless it's the empty set. You can then explain the concept of a partial function. A partial function $X \rightarrow Y$ is:

1. A pair $(A,f),$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $f : A \rightarrow Y$ is a function. (Remark: The set $A$ in definition (1) is sometimes called the domain of definition of the partial function. I prefer to call it the *preimage*.)
2. A function $X \rightarrow Y + 1$.
3. A function $X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_{\leq 1}(Y)$.

The reason $2$ and $3$ are the same is because $x$ and $\{x\}$ are basically the same thing (except in very specific set theoretic-contexts where they have to be regarded as different).

So, what have we learned?

Given a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between Hausdorff topological spaces, we get a partial function $$a \in X \mapsto \lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$$ going from $X$ to $Y$. Lets call this $\mathrm{Lim}(f)$. Think of $\mathrm{Lim}(f)$ as our best attempt at getting rid of any discontinuities in $f$. You can then explain that the failure to be continuous can arise from two sources. One source is that the preimage of $\mathrm{Lim}(f)$ may not be all of $X$. For example, consider $f(x) = 1/x$ with $f(0)$ defined to be $17$. The second source is this: even if the preimage of $\mathrm{Lim}(f)$ is all of $X$, nonetheless $\mathrm{Lim}(f)$ might be distinct from $f$. For example, consider $f(x) = x$ for $x \neq 21$ and define $f(21)=-35$.

By the way, this way of thinking about limits (namely, as sets) really helps with writing comprehensible proofs involving them. [Take this imvho borderline-flawed MIT proof that differentiability implies continuity](http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html). My issue is with the step $$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) = \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}g(x).$$ This is, of course, untrue in general, and needs to be carefully justified in every special case where it's invoked.

And yet with the limits-as-sets viewpoint, we don't need any careful justification in this particular case. Indeed, we can just replace this "law" with $$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) \supseteq \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}g(x),$$ which is actually true in full generality, and which is also enough to get the proof that differentiability implies continuity to work (try it).

Comment: I confess I don't see any problem with that proof that differentiability implies continuity. You say $\lim fg=\lim f\lim g$ is untrue in general. But it's true if both $\lim f$ and $\lim  g$ exist (as real numbers), which is clearly the case in that proof.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, really there are two problems. The first is that its indistinguishable from the incorrect proof that assumes $\lim fg = \lim f \lim g$ is true in general. This means that if a non-expert submits the proof, it fails to demonstrate that the non-expert actually understands the logic. This also means that if an expert gives this proof to a non-expert, the non-expert could easily misunderstand how the proof works and thus be misled by a purportedly correct proof. And that bothers me a lot, because a genuinely correct proof should never mislead, only elucidate.

Comment: The second problem is that you're taking a limit as $x$ goes to a point at which $f(x)$ isn't even defined. This directly contradicts the usual definition of a limit, which is (rather unwisely) only stated for total functions. To fix the problem, you have to write something like this: Let $X$ and $Y$ denote topological spaces and suppose $A \subseteq X$ is a subset. Then given a function $f : A \rightarrow Y$, we say that $f$ has a limit at $a \in A$ if and only if <whatever>. In general, I think that we really need to take partial functions a lot more seriously.

Comment: "The second problem is that you're taking a limit as $x$ goes to a point at which $f(x)$ isn't even defined. This directly contradicts the usual definition of a limit..." What? Then the definition of a _derivative_ contradicts the usual definition of a limit.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ requires that $f(a)$ be defined. But it's simply not so.  Trust me. Or find a calculus book - half of the interesting "find the limit" problems are limits "of the form" $0/0$. Or look it up: Wikipedia gets it right: "The above definition of a limit is true even if $f(c) \ne L$. Indeed, the function $f$ need not even be defined at $c$." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)
"

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're confusing the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ with the definition of "$f$ is continuous at $a$". The first definition talks about $0<|x-a|<\delta$, while if the second is stated in terms of epsilons and deltas instead of limits it involves $|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: About the supposed first problem with that proof: The identity $(a+b)^2=a^2+3ab+b^2$ is also not true in general. So even in a context where $a$  and $b$ are clearly real  numbers one should carefully explain why that identity holds before using it? The implication "if $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$" is not true in general...

Comment: Heh - of course $3=2$ above, sorry...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, in regards to your second comment about the identity $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$, there's an important distinction here that only becomes apparent from a type-theoretic perspective. In that viewpoint, the condition $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is a boolean) is replaced with the judgement $a : \mathbb{R}$, which is a variable declaration. And thus from a type-theoretic perspective, $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab+b^2$ really is true in general, as long as you know the types of $a$ and $b$. To decide whether to justify the use of a line of math, a good rule of thumb is to ask whether that...

Comment: ... line is true unconditionally, given only the types of the variables. If it's not, my opinion is that justification needs to be given. I'll do some research regarding your first point and see what I find. I have a hunch most books get this wrong, however.

Comment: Also note how much notationally clearer my suggestion is compared to the usual alternative. Rewriting that awful MIT proof ever so slightly: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} (x-x_0)\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ $$\supseteq \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} (x-x_0) \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} $$ $$= 0 f'(x_0) $$ $$= 0 \mbox{ because } f'(x_0) \mbox{ has exactly one element by hypothesis }$$ (Not really sure how to get the text left-justified properly, but you get the idea)

Comment: "I have a hunch most books get this wrong, however." it's not at all clear to me what you mean by "get it wrong" here. _If_ a book says or implies that the existence of $\lim_{x\to a}f((x)$ requires that $f(a)$ be defined then the book gets it wrong. But I don't see how there can be such a book, since then it's impossible to give the usual definition of the derivative.

Comment: So. We're not allowed to use without comment an intuitively obvious and easily proved result, in a context where the hypotheses are _obviously_ satisfied, but we _are_ allowed to use something without comment if it follows from the types of the variables. This seems somewhat arbitrary. So far the only justification for this rule is that you say so.... (It's a good thing that you're not in charge, because if you were the definition  of the derivative would be invalid.)

Comment: @DavidCUllrich, you're allowed to do whatever you want. On that note, since I find your points to be silly misinterpretations of what I'm actually saying and your tone to be slightly obnoxious, I don't think I'll bother talking to you anymore.

Comment: Silly misinterpretations, right. When you wrote ""The second problem is that you're taking a limit as $x$ goes to a point at which $f(x)$ isn't even defined. This directly contradicts the usual definition of a limit..."" I "interpreted" that as saying that the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ requires that $f(a)$ be defined. I can't imagine how else to "interpret" it. And yes, it follows that the definition of $f'$ is invalid - not an ideal thing to say, credibility-wise.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I don't understand your reasoning. Just because it breaks the definition doesn't mean authors don't do it, and then just fail to notice the problem. [Proof wiki nearly gets it right](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_of_Function), except that (a) the way they use the word mapping contradicts their own definition of "mapping", and (b) under their definition I'm not allowed to compute the limits of the partial function $$x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \frac{x(x-1)}{x(x-1)}$$ due to the fact that it fails to be defined at more than one point. Mathematical convention...

Comment: ... partially saves us, by dictating that we can play fast-and-loose with the domains of things w/o annoying people too much, so that I can change the domain of the above partial function w/o explicit saying I'm doing it, thereby saving the ProofWiki definition. However, in my opinion, students shouldn't have to exploit these kinds of subtle conventions to salvage problematic definitions. They should just be given definitions that are unproblematic. I accept that *you* give them definitions that work at a strict technical level. I just don't accept that this is 100% normal.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I'd also like to emphasize that the set-of-values viewpoint advocated in my answer helps us speak and write much more clearly. Under the usual viewpoint, we're not really allowed to say "$f'(x)$ exists" because if it doesn't exist, we shouldn't be referring to it and claiming it has properties, because after all, there's nothing we're talking about. Whereas under the point of view I advocate, we can say "$f'(x)$ has an element" and it works fine, we're just saying that this is a singleton rather than empty. Again, I accept that mathematical convention allows us to get away...

Comment: ... with this kind of stuff just by tolerating abuses of notation. But for myself, I don't see why we tolerate these abuses when, after all, a formalization of the relevant notions is all three of easy to find, syntactically useful, and conceptually clarifying.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, another reason to teach partial functions is that they justify the validity of certain questions in high school that make no sense from a total-functional viewpoint. In particular, in high school students are sometimes given a function like $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 3}$ and asked to find the largest domain of definition for this function. From a total-functional viewpoint, this is very dodgy - we're not meant to define $f$ without specifying the domain beforehand. But from a partial function viewpoint, it's fine. We're defining a partial function...

Comment: ... $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-3}$, and then the problem is to find $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, the preimage of $f$. The mystery goes away, the abuses of notation becomes unnecessary, and all we have to do is accept that partial functions are sometimes useful - a fact that, btw, computer scientists accepted a long time ago.